# Getting started with Spartacus and integrating with Hybris

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am a SAP Hybris commerce developer.

Recently we are migrating to Spartacus.Does it integrate with SAP Hybris?What are the learning paths for this?

Answer (score 1):

Spartacus does integrate with hybris using APIs.
For learning paths check the official docs on our GitHub page here: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront and our wiki here: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/wiki